Spring boot active profile not picked up on windows but works on linux
We have a spring boot application running on linux with the standard command :-
java -jar feed.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev

This works fine, it displays the log line
"The following 1 profile is active : "dev" "
The exact same command with the same Jar file on Windows says :-
"No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default""
SpringBoot version is 2.7.4
java is 11.0.21
Why doesnt it work on windows ?

It's always a good practice to add -D for VM args:
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev feed.jar
The -D arg should be before feed.jar
Not entirely sure why Windows terminal behaves differently.
